# Python + Fpdf2: unicode encoding in text_annotation

Tags: python, fpdf

I am using fpdf2 2.5 to dynamically create a pdf in python 3.6. The pdf contains unicode characters. So far I have handled it like this:

```
pdf.add_font('DejaVuSerif', '', FONT_PATH_FOR_PDF + '/DejaVuSerif.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font('DejaVuSerif')
pdf.write_html("<h4><font face='DejaVuSerif'>Text containing unicode</font></h4>")
```

Now I want to use text annotations, and there I am running into problems. I have tried:

```
pdf.text_annotation(x=currentX, y=currentY, text=u"καλημέρα")
```

and

```
pdf.text_annotation(x=currentX, y=currentY, text=my_text_variable)
```

In both cases I get an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 230-237: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Does anyone know how to set the encoding for text annotations to Unicode?

Comment: You may want to look at package PyMuPDF: it supports freetext annotations having any mixture of Latin, CJK, Cyrillic and Greek.

Comment: I understand. I will use a different method to display the text I want, rather than put it in an annotation.